# How to work with grails and multiple postgresql database schemata

Tags: database, postgresql, grails

Sometimes we have one application which uses multiple database schemata.

E.g. There is a table company1.someTable which looks exactly like company2.someTable. But some users have access to company1.*, others to company2.* oder both.

Is there an easy way to tell grails to work with a database like this and let the user select the schema?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Datasources plugin.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/datasources

I have managed to connect two different mysql databases (postgres should be the same).

In grails project run command:

grails install-plugin datasources

Create file conf/Datasources.conf, which will hold the second schema (the default is still in Dataseource.conf)

for example:

datasources = {

```
datasource(name: 'wadmin') {
    driverClassName('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
    dbCreate("update")
    url("jdbc:mysql://localhost/wadmin-test")
    username("xx")
    password("xx")
    // here you will write list of classes in particular schema
    domainClasses([cz.webarchiv.wadmin.Curator, cz.webarchiv.wadmin.Publisher])
    dialect(org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect)
    pooled(true)
    environments(['development'])
}
```

}

Mind the small "s" letter in datasources.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but I think this plugin does not exactli cover my needs. I would like to have one application for multiple schemata/databases with the same tables where the user can select which one he would like to use.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. But still you need that kind of funcionality, but based on some parameter rather than class name. From understanding of the source: http://goo.gl/KTDdA I would look into persistenceInterceptor bean.

Other approach (more messy) would be creating superclass, which will be inherited to subclasses. E.g. package.company1.Class & package.company2.Class extends package.SuperClass. This way you could use this plugin. But I don't like it.. it was just thought :)

Comment: Thank you anyway. The following blog article is probably closer to me needs: http://www.leebutts.com/2008/07/switchable-grails-datasource.html